# Packing/tessellating 4 dimensional space fully by polytopes? Give examples.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, polytopes, packing-problem, tessellations

What is a shortlist of first few simplest (say 5~10 simplest) possible shapes of polyhedra/polytopes (with a minimum number of edges shared) to pack the 4-dimensional flat space (say $\mathbb{R}^4$) fully?

By the simplest, I require it to be "**with a minimum number of vertex/edge/face/volume shared**."

As far as I know,

- The 4-dimensional Tesseract (sort of 4-dimensional "cubic") works:

which requires

0: each 0-vertex V is shared by 16 neighbored cubics.

1: each 1-edge E is shared by 8 neighbored cubics.

2: each 2-face F is shared by 4 neighbored cubics.

3: each 3-volume U is shared by 2 neighbored cubics.

(to make a comparison, the 3-dimensional cubic works to do packing/tessellating in 3D. Where

0: each 0-vertex V is shared by 8 neighbored cubics.

1: each 1-edge E is shared by 4 neighbored cubics.

2: each 2-face F is shared by 2 neighbored cubics.

we can possibly cut out part of 4-dimensional Tesseracts to do fully packing/tessellating in 4D.

> - what else polytopes do you know to do packing/tessellating in 4D fully?

Answer (score 2):

The *regular* tetracombs are

- [x4o3o3o4o](https://bendwavy.org/klitzing/incmats/test.htm) : tesselation of tesseracts
- [x3o3o4o3o](https://bendwavy.org/klitzing/incmats/hext.htm) : tesselation of 16-cells
- [x3o4o3o3o](https://bendwavy.org/klitzing/incmats/icot.htm) : tesselation of 24-cells

but lots of further [tetracombs](https://bendwavy.org/klitzing/dimensions/flat.htm#4D) are known.

--- rk